# Query for altering the columns default value

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, alter

I have googled a lot with no success , just need to know the query for altering the column default value.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear or provide an example?

Comment: got a column name status with a default value false i need to change that default value to 0

Comment: table = dbo.getstatus, columnname = status , sql server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Drop the old default value:

```
ALTER TABLE <TableName> DROP CONSTRAINT <DF_ContstraintName>
```

2) Add new default value:

```
ALTER TABLE <TableName> ADD CONSTRAINT
<DF_ContstraintName> DEFAULT <Value> FOR <ColumnName>
```

Comment: Needs to drop the existiong constraint first though `ALTER TABLE <TableName> DROP CONSTRAINT <DF_ContstraintName>`